# Customising the contact form

Tags: emails

I'm using the contact form inside a block on my frontpage, however the labels are pretty ugly, and I'd like to customise the form a bit.

Is there some template file I can grab and put in my theme? I'm using Drupal 7.

I've done some looking but no luck.

Comment: Does this help you? I'm afraid I use Drupal 6 so can't test. http://bri-space.com/content/theming-contact-form-drupal-7-contactsiteform

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a non-Drupal alternative to create my contact form:
[jQuery Contact Form](http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/)

I modified the CSS heavily however :)